# WinForms: How to get a selected row on grid

Tags: c#, winforms, grid

I want to create a form which I can open tables within different database and delete some lines.
[image]

looks like this. the tables are different. so I use

```
boxGrid.Controls.Clear();
DataGridView g = GetTableGrid(databaseName);
boxGrid.Controls.Add(g);
```

`GetTableGrid()` will generate a new DataGridView and replace the one before
it works will on changing table. but causes problems for me to get the selected row in the table to delete.

What can I do?
I only need to get the first col in the row. It is the primary key in the database.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` !! This is wrong and confusing and and bound to get wrong answers wasting everybody's time.. Always call things by their __right__ name! - So what is it? a `DataGridView`? .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is that you are always creating a new datagridview whenever the user selects a new table (i would assume its the buttons below the datagridview)

What you can do is before adding the datagridview on your boxgrid object, you can add an [SelectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) to it.

```
boxGrid.Controls.Clear();
DataGridView g = GetTableGrid(databaseName);
g.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(dvg_SelectionChanged);
boxGrid.Controls.Add(g);
```

and then you can get the value you are looking for like this

```
private void dvg_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
     DataGridView dvg = (DataGridView)sender;
     //Check first if datagridview has data and
     //Check if you are selecting a valid row
     if (dvg.Rows.Count > 0 && dvg.CurrentCell.RowIndex > 0)
     {
         int index = dvg.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

         DataGridViewRow row= dvg.Rows[index];  
         string mykey = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["columnName"].Value);
         //Or you can store the information you've got here to some
         //Variable you can use to open the form you want.         
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to get a certain column (in this case, the first one) of a clicked row you can do the following (it's how I do it):

```
private void yourGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
//makes sure a row is selected
     if (yourGridView.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
     {
         int selectedrowindex = yourGridView.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

         DataGridViewRow selectedRow = yourGridView.Rows[selectedrowindex];  

//guessing you´re storing your value in a variable
          string a = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["columnName"].Value);   
//where columnName is the name of the column you want the value printed of...        
     }
 }
```